# PHP JQuery Ajax insert not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Normally works but when trying for ajax insert does not work.

Here is my form(no form action in html):

```
name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" id="submit">
```

Here is the add.php file code

```
require_once('conn.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query = mysql_query("insert into toy(name) values('$name')");
if ($query) {
    echo "Data inserted";
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

And here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "add.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: $("#name").val()
    },
    success: function(data){
          alert("Data Save: " + data);
     }
});
});
```

});

Thanks in advance for suggestion.

Comment: Are you getting the MySQL error (failure to insert), or does the Ajax call fail before that?

Edit: Nevermind. See you got it fixed!

Comment: no. Solved after adding preventDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent default form submit:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   // do your ajax

});
```

Comment: If I change my code
`data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',`
Alert not working. How to fix that

Comment: you are returning text from server not json, so will cause a json parsing error